# SQS Error Message: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have a Lambda function that is created inside a serverless framework setup. I am trying to pass in a queue url as an ENV variable, when I do that it results in the below error message. I've checked multiple times for wrong format in the queue url, no typos. I have also tried including the actual url as a plain string without the variable/string replacement. I have also tried it as seen below but with `'` around it, no luck either.

Looking around online it seems like people have mostly just had bad urls with typos and since that isn't my case I am unsure what might be wrong. I was hoping someone might have an idea on what is wrong and how to fix it.

Error message

```
SQS Error Message: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
```

serverless.yml

```
service: email-service-serverless
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ${ssm:/pae/${opt:stage}/securityGroupIds}
    subnetIds:
      - ${ssm:/pae/${opt:stage}/subnetIds}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${opt:accID}:email_queue
      Action:
        - 'sqs:*'
  environment:
    SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${ssm:/pae/${opt:stage}/SENDGRID_API_KEY~true} 
    emailQueue: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${opt:accID}/email_queue
# you can overwrite defaults here
region: us-east-1

functions:
  email:
    handler: handler.email
    memorySize: 128 # in MB
    events:
      - sqs: 
          arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${opt:accID}:email_queue
          batchSize: 1
```

EDIT**

Today is a new day, about 18 hours after creating the queues which were part of the issue. For s and giggles I tried the exact same code as last night and to my surprise it worked. I'm now wondering why it wouldn't work last night but did today. I am guessing some sort of cache though I don't know of any caches in cloudformation or sqs creation, maybe there is though?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've checked in the console to see if it is there and I've copy/paste the url from the console. The logicalID that the cloudformation console shows is `EmailEventSourceMappingSQSEmailqueuedev` then in the status reason it gives the error message from my OP